# REGEX - Palavras em maiúsculo no meio da frase

Tags: javascript, regex, intellij-idea

Existe algum regex/replace para tornar palavras em maiúsculo no meio da frase para minúsculo?

(Sim, eu poderia passar tudo para Lower) mas tem um porém nisto, a regra deve ser ignorada caso a palavra for posterior a ponto (.).

Exemplo:

- Usuário Não Autenticado. Contate o ADM.

para:

- Usuário não autenticado. Contate o ADM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar esta regex:

```
/^[^]([^.]*)/
```

Ela captura o texto do início até o último caractere antes do primeiro `.`, ignorando o primeiro caractere (`[^]`) armazenando no grupo 1. Depois você converte para minúsculo com `.toLowerCase()` no `replace`:

```js
var string = "UsuÁrio Não AUtenticadO. Contate o ADM.";

var res = string.match(/^[^]([^.]*)/)[1];
string = string.replace(res,res.toLowerCase());

console.log(string);
```

Ou você pode pegar tudo até a palavra "Contate":

```
/[^](.+?(?=.\sContate))/
```

```js
var string = "UsuÁrio Não AUtenticadO. Contate o ADM.";

var res = string.match(/[^](.*?(?=.\sContate))/)[1];
string = string.replace(res,res.toLowerCase());

console.log(string);
```

### EDIT

Caso haja pontos no meio da string, esta regex ignora a primeira letra maiúscula após o ponto. Como o resultado retorna uma array com mais de 1 *match*, foi necessário fazer um loop na array ignorando o último *match* (`Contate o ADM`):

```
/([^.\sA-Z][^.]*)/g
```

```js
var string = "Usuário Não Autenticado. Contate o ADM. Em Caso De Ou O A. Vou À Bahia. UsuÁrio Não AUtenTicadO. Ok Vamos testa. Contate o ADM.";

var regex = /([^.\sA-Z][^.]*)/g
var res = string.match(regex);

for(let x=0; x<res.length-1; x++){
   string = string.replace(res[x],res[x].toLowerCase());
}

console.log(string);
```

Comment: var string = "UsuÁrio Não AUtenticadO. Ok Vamos testa. Contate o ADM."; .. fiz uma alteração e não deu certo

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Verdade. Reli a pergunta e me pareceu que quando houver algum ponto no meio, a primeira palavra deve manter o caps. Blz, vou tentar arrumar isso na resposta.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Consegui com uma regex mais simples. Fiz um Edit na resposta.

Comment: @danieltakeshi Atualizei o Edit da resposta. Creio que esteja correto. Obg!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar este Regex:

`(?<!\.)(?:\s([A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd][A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd]*[a-z\u00E0-\u00ff][a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ffA-Z]*)|\s(A|O|À)(?=\s|\.))`

ou

`(?<!\.)(?:\s([A-ZÀ-Ý][A-ZÀ-Ý]*[a-zà-ÿ][a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]*)|\s(A|O|À)(?=\s|\.))`

E a [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rf4axx/10).

Porém, há o problema com Nomes Próprios, mas se não utilizá-los este Regex pode capturar o que você deseja.

Este Regex captura palavras gerais e textos em geral e não somente a frase de exemplo, sugiro nas próximas perguntas que postar formular mais exemplos de Regex e que sejam "a prova de erros".

### Explicação

#### 1a Alternativa

`(?<!\.)\s([A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd][A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd]*[a-z\u00E0-\u00ff]+[a-z\u00E0-\u00ffA-Z\u00C0-\u00dd]*)`

- `(?<!\.)` - **Negative Lookbehind** - Se houver o caracter `.` antes da palavra, não captura a string.
- `\s` - Captura qualquer espaço em branco (igual a `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`).
- `([A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd][A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd]*[a-z\u00E0-\u00ff]+[A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd]*)` - **Grupo de Captura ()** - Captura palavras que não sejam completamente maiúsculas.

  - `[A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd]` - Primeira letra maiúscula - Corresponde uma letra entre A-Z e entre o index 192 e 221 do Unicode.
  - `[A-Z\u00C0-\u00dd]*` - A segunda letra pode ser maiúscula ou não - Corresponde zero a infinitas letras entre A-Z e entre o index 192 e 221 do Unicode.
  - `[a-z\u00E0-\u00ff]` - É necessária letra minúscula na palavra - Corresponde uma letra entre a-z e entre o index 224 e 255 do Unicode.
  - `[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ffA-Z]*` - Após a presença de minúscula, captura letras minúsculas ou maiúsculas - Corresponde zero a infinitas letras entre a-z e entre A-Z e entre o index 192 e 255 do Unicode.

Não captura letras totalmente maiúsculas, pois podem ser siglas.

#### Ou

`|`

#### 2a Alternativa

Em casos com os pronomes o, a ou crase maiúsculos. Que são letras "sozinhas".

`\s(A|O|À)(?=\s|\.)`

- `\s` - Captura qualquer espaço em branco (igual a `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`).
- `(A|O|À)` - **Grupo de Captura** - Captura literalmente A ou O ou À.
- `(?=\s|\.)` - **Positive Lookahead** - Após o grupo de captura, é necessário um espaço em branco `\s` ou `|` um ponto `\.`.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer uma solução *clean* usando regex utilize essa expressão para captura:

```
(^.)|(ADM)|((?<!\. )[A-zÀ-ÿ ])
```

E essa expressão para substituição:

```
$1$2\L$3
```

No seu código JS, você pode utilizar:

```
str.replace(/(^.)|(ADM)|((?<!\. )[A-zÀ-ÿ ])/, "$1$2\L$3")
```

Você pode testar essas expressões nesse [link](https://regex101.com/r/WdAthT/1)

---

**Explicação captura**

`(^.)` - Captura o primeiro caractere para evitar que ele fique minúsculo.
`|` - OU 
`(ADM)` - Captura exatamente ADM 
`|` - OU 
`(?<!\. )` - negative lookbehind, evita que a sequencia a seguir capture se houver `.`  antes.
`[A-zÀ-ÿ ]` - captura todos os caracteres, sendo acentuados minúsculos ou maiúsculos.

**Explicação substituição**

`$1` - grupo de captura 1 (`(^.)`) 
`$2` - grupo de captura 2 (`(ADM)`)
`\L$3` - grupo de captura 3 minúsculo (`(?<!\. )[A-zÀ-ÿ ]`)